# Formatting Timestamps in Java

Tags: java, date

Is there a way to format a UTC time into any arbitrary string format I want in java?  Basically I was thinking of having some class take the timestamp and I pass it is string telling it how I want it formated, and it returns the formatted string for me.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The java.text.SimpleDateFormat class provides formatting and parsing for dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

The javadoc header for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is a good source of detailed information. There is also a [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) with example usages.

Answer (score 28):

The [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class or [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) should get you there. For example, http://www.epochconverter.com/ lists the following example to convert a epoch time to human readable timestamp with Java:

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

Answer (score 4):

Date instances are insufficient for some purposes.

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Joda time integrates with Hibernate and other databases.

Answer (score 3):

One gotcha to be aware of is that SimpleDateFormat is NOT thread-safe.  Do not put it in a static field and use it from multiple threads concurrently.