# Java get hours from a timestamp

Tags: java

I'm reading the timestamp from a file, and convert it using SimpleDataFormat to the timestamp format received from SQL, for some reason, I have to compare the minutes and seconds of both the stamps. Is there an optimized to extract the hours (without parsing it)  from the stamp I have converted using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: In what object are you holding the data? Just a String?

Comment: Without parsing it? How then? Google for "parse date in Java".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting Timestamps in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129181/formatting-timestamps-in-java)

Comment: a code- and/or output-example of what you have and what exactly you want would be a good way to improve this question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `SimpleDateFormat` which can parse a give date to format you require.

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Read more about `SimpleDateFormat` at [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Cheers !!

Comment: this is not doing what he asked for.

Comment: @MK How do you know what he asked for? The question is at least too vague and at most a duplicate.

Comment: @Jim well, at the very least we know that he want to extract, not format?  And nothing here is doing any extraction of data?

Comment: @MK The problem is way too vague for **any** kind of answer.

Comment: @Jim I disagree.  It is clear that he has a string representing a timestamp and he wants to extract particular fields out of it.  The only unclear part is what "without parsing" means, which I interpret as "without writing my own code for parsing dates", not "without using libraries that parse dates" (because that would be weird thing to ask for).

Comment: @MK The question has no clear research effort. The problem is ill defined. There's no code posted as to what he has tried or what worked/didn't work. You should know better than that at your rep level.

Comment: @Shoe that's not what he asked for. His title says, "get hours from timestamp"

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse("Wed Sep 4 13:41:12 UTC 2013");
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    // ...
    System.exit(-1);
}
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.setTime(date);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

(of course you will have to change date format to match your string, I just put in a random one from the internets)

Comment: What's the point of parsing the `Date` if you just create a new `Calendar` and do absolutely nothing with the `Date`?

Answer (score -1):

The quick and easy way, if you have a string with the date in some fixed format:

```
String str = "2005-10-30 T 10:46 UTC";
String hours = str.substring(13, 15);
String minutes = str.substring(16, 18);
```

Comment: Making several unsafe assumptions with your code. (Didn't down vote)

Comment: Yeah this could be really bad. Unsafe assumptions.