# How to convert Object as timestamp to formatted date

Tags: java, timestamp

How to convert Object as timestamp to formatted date?

I have printed out timestamp(

> 1395500668

) that is in Object.
I want to format this and print it out like

> yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s

Comment: No efforts ? Or at least share whatever you tried

Comment: As [@Andy897](http://stackoverflow.com/users/969107/andy897) pointed out, it would be good to show where you've looked for help so far and possibly what you have already tried. It seems this [SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129181/formatting-timestamps-in-java) will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @HeiJai You need to tell us what `Object` is, "the timestamp is in Object" doesn't really mean much. For all we know it could be anything (is it a `Timestamp`? a `String`? something else entirely?)

Comment: Use "long" and "new date" return "null", the object get by json decode that's a timestamp.

Comment: @HeiJai How exactly are you decoding it from JSON and what does your input JSON look like? We're trying to help you, but you need to help *us* help you by giving enough information for us to know what is going on.

Comment: @JasonC My JSON code : JSONObject json_Object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json); json_time = json_Object.get("time");

Comment: @HeiJai You do not seem to be using Jackson. Are you using GWT? Don't make us pull teeth here. Until you can give us a complete description of your problem, you will not get an answer here. All the tools you need to do this have been given in the answers below. Use your problem-solving skills to figure out how to get a `String` or a `long` containing your timestamp value from your JSON object. Consult the documentation for the JSON parser you are using for more information.

Comment: @JasonC I'm using JSON-Simple to decode that get Object for me, Then I getted a timestamp, I want to format it to String with formatted date.

Comment: It looks like your question has been closed due to lack of sufficient information to diagnose the problem (i.e. because we're not psychic, and can't read your mind or see your code). If you'd like to see it reopened, you may wish to edit it to include a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a string that represents epoch time in seconds (as you have not told us what your `Object` actually is), first [convert it to a `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29):

```
long epoch = Long.parseLong("1395500668");
```

You'll then need to convert it to milliseconds:

```
epoch *= 1000;
```

Then you can convert it to a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) using [the `Date` constructor that takes millisecond epoch time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29):

```
Date date = new Date(epoch);
```

And finally you can format that `Date` as a string using [standard formatting techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java?rq=1).

Comment: The timestamp is in Object
So that returns "null"

Comment: @HeiJai What returns `null`? You need to tell us what `Object` is, "the timestamp is in Object" doesn't really mean much.

Comment: The object get by json decode that's a timestamp.

Comment: I tried hardly, your code may work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First convert the `timestamp value` into `Date` and then format the date into your desired format using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(new Long(1395500668) * 1000);
String dateStr = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s").format(date);
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

It outputs:

```
2014-03-22 8:4:28
```

Comment: The timestamp is in Object So that returns "null"

Comment: @HeiJai not sure what you mean. But you can try this one: `java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(obj.toString()) * 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Convert it first into a `Date` first by casting the `Object` into a `Timestamp` and then using the `getTime()` method as shown in [How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java?rq=1)

Then use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date as needed as shown in [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java?rq=1)